# Subnet routing problem

Tags: ssh, icmp

In my LAN I have an openwrt router configured with IP 10.0.0.1. It is the default gateway (and dhcp server) in my LAN 10.0.0.0/24.
Now I have a new network, say 10.9.0.0/24 used by virtual machines. The gateway to this network is a host with two interfaces: 10.0.0.9 and 10.9.0.9.

Everything works fine if I add a route to each client (*route add -net 10.9.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.9*). But I can not normally do this (due to many devices I can't access to configure).

I added a static route to openwrt on 10.0.0.1. Now I get an icmp "Redirect Host" if I try to ping a VM host; but the ping works. It looks correct for me.

The problem is that an ssh connection attempt freezes with this configuration (after saying "connection established" in verbose mode). What goes wrong here?

Comment: The ICMP redirect seems to be working properly, so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. Is there any firewalling/iptables on the 10.0.0.9 router? You may have to diagnose this with `tcpdump` or `wireshark` on that router by packet-dumping both interfaces (10.9.0.9 and 10.9.0.9) as well as perhaps on the SSH client and SSH server in order to see where at which point the packets are being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the problem sits in front of the computer: I inspected the packets with tcpdump and found out that the direction from 10.9.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 was not working.

After this I remembered that a "ufw" was running on my LAN client which causes all the problems. I had installed ufw for testing purposes a few weeks ago and did not configured it at all. I could not figured out how and what exactly ufw was blocking. After an "ufw disable" **and** a restart everything worked. I also flushed the iptables before so ufw did some other things.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP redirect is a ugly thing - which is blocked by many machines.

Can you `traceroute` the VMs from the openwrt router? How did you make the route on the openwrt side (also with `route add -net 10.9.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.9`)?

Does the gateway have the right routes? Have you done http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/ in both the openwrt router and your gateway? Is the subnet everywhere the /24 (not the default /8)?

This should help to identify your problem.

Comment: I think that's an undeservedly negative comment about ICMP redirects. Yes, it doesn't always work optimally (usually do to rate-limiting and such, not outright blocking), but there is a fallback so that it is not essential for it to work: the packet hairpins through the router. More importantly, a whole subnet full of unmanaged machines on which you don't want to maintain or can't maintain a bunch of static routes is exactly the right use case for ICMP recirects.